# Spring batch meta data tables significance

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

Spring batch creates meta data tables in database automatically. as of now I forced spring batch to create metadata tables in memory as per one of the stack-overflow answer. As per the documentation I learnt that metadata tables are used for recovery and restart. My batch job do not require restart because as per my functionality I can simply process the file in next batch. But unable to understand what kind of recovery spring batch provide by using metadata tables. I am simply asking this question because I would like to know is it advisory to turn off creation of meta data tables? Thank you.

Comment: The metadata is there to know which job and steps have run as well as how far it got. If you restart a job it will pick up from where it left. If there is no metadata (like in your case) there is no restart possible. It also shows you how many rows were read and written, how long a step and job took etc. which is all interesting information as well (you could detect performance degradation for your job or steps with that).

Comment: `Spring batch creates meta data tables in database automatically`: This is not correct, it is up to you to create those tables upfront. Otherwise, +1 to what M. Deinum said.